# Using many -o in bash find

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a small script to find all the video files on my computer.

```
#!/bin/bash

videos=("avi" "mp4" "mkv" "m4v" "wmv" "ogg" "mov") # etc...

for i in ${videos[@]}
do
    find ~ -iname "*.$i"
done
```

This becomes prohibitively slow, as the program has to loop through the files many times.  The only alternate solution I could find was

```
find ~ -iname "*.avi" -o -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.mkv" # and on and on...
```

Is there a better, more idiomatic way of doing it?

Comment: You could use one regex that match every file type like `/\.(?:avi|mp4|mov)$/i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `-regextype egrep -regex`, example :

```
find -regextype egrep -regex '.*\.(avi|mp4|mkv|etc)'
```

Comment: For OSX users: `find -E . -regex '.*\.(avi|mp4|mkv|etc)'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-iregex` option:

```
find . -type f -iregex '.*\.\(avi\|mp4\|mkv\)'
```

Comment: For OSX users: `find -E . -iregex '.*\.(avi|mp4|mkv|etc)'`.